# Lightning report display problem when using Edge

Tags: lightning, reporting, microsoft-edge

I have a Lightning report with two group by fields and various fields in the details.  The report is producing the correct data but does not display correctly when using the Edge browser.

For example, assume the report groups on animals.  If I have two kinds of animals - cats and dogs, there is a grouping for cat with details of different kinds of cats and a grouping for dog with details of different kinds of dogs.  The details don't line up correctly.  For example, on the screen a dog breed might show up next to the cat grouping.  Also, the subtotal labels show up next to detail records instead of next to the subtotal values.  You can see that the lines that should delineate a group and its details don't line up.

The difference in the line might seem insignificant, but it is really throwing off the report and is providing misleading information.

[image]

This doesn't happen to me when using Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: It is unlikely that SFSE can provide assistance regarding browser support for out-of-the-box Salesforce features. Edge is listed as a supported browser; have you filed a case?

Comment: I did file a case.  One of the group by fields is a multi-select picklist.  I am thinking that is part of the problem.  However, since Edge and multi-select picklists are supported, I think it should work correctly.

Comment: This was resolved with a patch to Summer '19 release.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved with a patch to Summer '19 release.  I don't have a link. Salesforce technical support called me a week after I submitted the case and told me to try to run the report again. They told me a patch resolved the problem. I didn't question it because the reports ran correctly.

Comment: If so, please include a link to the relevant Release Note.

Comment: I don't have a link.  Salesforce technical support called me a week after I submitted the case and told me to try to run the report again.  They told me a patch resolved the problem.  I didn't question it because the reports ran correctly.

Comment: Ok, so **[edit]** your post to include that contextual information please.